# How to package python code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, setup.py

My project looks like this:

```
.
├── code
│   └── __pycache__
├── data
│   ├── all_data
│   ├── test
│   └── train
└── models
└── setup.py
```

The **code** folder contains all the code that I want to package up nicely so that I can do a pip install on my local machine. I have a **setup.py** file which is a sister file to the **code** folder. The code in my **setup.py** is as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['numpy==1.13.0','tensorflow==1.2.0','sklearn','matplotlib']
setup(
      name = 'code',
      version = '0.1',
      py_modules=['code.abc','code.xyz','code.ijk','code.pqr'],
      install_requires = REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
      zip_safe=False
     )
```

There is an empty **__init__.py** file inside the **code** folder. However, when I execute the command

```
python setup.py sdist
```

the tar file is created but I cannot import any of the files: **abc**, **xyz**, **ijk**, or **pqr**.

When I type:

```
import code
dir(code)
```

all I get it is this:

```
['CommandCompiler', 'InteractiveConsole', 'InteractiveInterpreter', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'compile_command', 'interact', 'softspace', 'sys', 'traceback']
```

None of the modules inside the **code** folder were packaged. How can I make sure they are?

Comment: Try adding `packages = ['code']` in the `setup()` call.

Comment: I did all that. Nothing seems to work. Even tried various combinations of arguments